# Using R try catch to download PDFs of the web

Tags: r, url, for-loop, download, try-catch

I'm trying to download PDFs using a table containing links. Due to inconsistent formatting of the links, I have created different versions of the same links residing in different columns. For privacy reasons I can't disclose the links, but here is what I did.

```
links <- data.frame(links1,links2,links3,links4)
filenames <- str_c(format(seq.Date(from = as.Date("2015-04-01"), 
                               to = Sys.Date(), by = "day"),"%Y_%m_%d"),".pdf")
```

After having created all the versions and the names, here I try to write a loop wrapped in `Try-Catch` to continue despite the link not being correct. my goal is to when it doesn't find the link on column `links$links1[3]` to look at the other columns on the same row to find a working link.

Here is my try:

```
for (i in seq_along(links[,1])) {
      #using trycatch to bipass the error when url doesn't exist
      tryCatch({
      if (!file.exists(str_c(folder,"/",filenames[i]))) { 
                  download.file(links[i,1], filenames[i], mode = "wb")
          print(paste0("Downloading: ", filenames[i]))
                  } }, error = function(e){

                             for (j in seq_along(links[i,])){
                               tryCatch({

                               download.file(links[i,j], filenames[i], mode = "wb")
                             }, error = function(e){}

                          )
                             }
                  }

      )


}
```

For some reason its not picking up PDFs uploaded on April 9th 2015 and possibly other dates too.

Comment: You are including `2015_04_09` in your range.  Is there any chance that there were no uploads on that and certain other days?

Comment: I pasted the URL in the browser and the PDF is there.

Comment: if this is an unauthenticated website on the public internet there is no privacy and i rly hope these are sensitive PDFs is that is the case. as far as the question goes, you may be hitting the site too fast and it's either overloading it or causing a web app firewall to kick in. if you used `httr::GET(url, httr::write_disk(filename), httr::verbose()` you could see the actual error being generated.

Answer (score 0):

The line `for (j in seq_along(links[i,])){` is causing the inner loop to retry the already failed link. If the link fails, it will therefore fail again in the inner loop. Your program continues happily, never having tried the other links.

You should skip over j = 1 in your inner for loop.

Here's a slightly modified version of your program showing what is happening.

```
links1 <- c('a','b','c')
links2 <- c('x','y','z')

links <- data.frame(links1,links2)

for (i in seq_along(links[,1])) {
  #using trycatch to bipass the error when url doesn't exist
  tryCatch({
        print(sprintf("trying: %s", links[i,1]))
        if( i == 2 ) {
          stop( simpleError("error"))
        }
     }, 
    error = function(e){
      for (j in seq_along(links[i,])){
        tryCatch({
          print(sprintf("falling back to %s", links[i,j]))
        }, 
        error = function(e){

        })
      }
    })
  }
```